# Avoid the wrapper.java.additional.<n>=<name>=<value>'s value to be displayed in the log file

Tags: logging, wrapper, java-service-wrapper

Is there any way to avoid the display of a wrapper.java.additional in the log file, when we use Java Service Wrapper?

For ex:

```
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Bar=Foo
```

will be displayed in the log file like:

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | <time/date> | INFO: Command line argument: -Bar=Foo
```